# Get birthday, gender, mobile phone in xmpp for android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack, google-talk

I use xmpp(asmack) to login and get contact from google talk. I look document about xmpp but not show about how to get birthday, gender, mobile phone... in xmpp in android. How can i get birthday, gender, mobile phone in xmpp? or have any other way can do that?

Comment: no any answers, i really need solution

Answer (score 1):

[XEP-54](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) describes the most common way to do this today.  [XEP-292](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0292.html) is the new version, which is starting to get some traction.  Implement both for forward/backward compatibility.

Note that Google's servers don't support this protocol, so you'll have to ask your contact's client directly using an IQ to the full JID:

```
<iq id='v3'
    to='jer@example.org/work'
    type='get'>
  <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
</iq>
```

Please do NOT do this every time you log in.  Please do NOT do this if the client you are connecting to supports [XEP-115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html) and doesn't say that it supports `vcard-temp`.  The responses that come back can be really large (due to embedded avatars), and cause a strain on the server infrastructure if you do too many of them.